# Create React App + Typescript In monorepo code sharing

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, monorepo

I currently have a monorepo where I have two (+) packages using yarn workspaces:

```
root
  /packages
    /common
    /web
  ...

root/package.json

  ...
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**"
    ],
  },
```

`web` is a plain create-react-app with the typescript template. I have some TS code in `common` I want to use in `web`, but it seems that CRA does not support compiling code outside of `src`, giving me an error when I try to import from `common` in `web`:

```
../common/state/user/actions.ts 4:66
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:66)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { UpdateUserParams } from './reducer';
| 
> export const login = createAction('USER/LOGIN')<{ username: string; password: string }>();
```

Thus, I followed the instructions at [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1333#issuecomment-347970625) after ejecting to include paths in `/common`, but it seems like `babel-loader` loads the files, but now isn't compiling them from typescript:

```
./common/state/user/actions.ts
SyntaxError: /Users/brandon/Code/apps/packages/common/state/user/actions.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (4:66)

  2 | import { UpdateUserParams } from './reducer';
  3 | 
> 4 | export const login = createAction('USER/LOGIN')<{ username: string; password: string }>();
    |                                                                   ^
  5 | 
  6 | export const logout = createAction('USER/LOGOUT')();
```

How can I get webpack / babel to compile code in common correctly? I know I can have `common` compile it's own code, but I'd rather not have to recompile code in common every time I want to make a change. Having each app do it itself is ideal.

Webpack.config.js:

```js
....
module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        // {
        //   test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
        //   enforce: 'pre',
        //   use: [
        //     {
        //       options: {
        //         cache: true,
        //         formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
        //         eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
        //         resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,

        //       },
        //       loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
        //     },
        //   ],
        //   include: paths.appSrc,
        // },
        {
          // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appLernaModules.concat(paths.appSrc), // MAIN CHANGE HERE!!!
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'),

                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'), { helpers: true }],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,

                // Babel sourcemaps are needed for debugging into node_modules
                // code.  Without the options below, debuggers like VSCode
                // show incorrect code and set breakpoints on the wrong lines.
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
            // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: {
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader',
              ),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 2,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: {
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader',
              ),
            },
            // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
            // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
            // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
            // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
            // that fall through the other loaders.
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined,
        ),
      ),
      ...
```

paths.js

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = require('url');

// Make sure any symlinks in the project folder are resolved:
// https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/637
const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

const envPublicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

function ensureSlash(inputPath, needsSlash) {
  const hasSlash = inputPath.endsWith('/');
  if (hasSlash && !needsSlash) {
    return inputPath.substr(0, inputPath.length - 1);
  } else if (!hasSlash && needsSlash) {
    return `${inputPath}/`;
  } else {
    return inputPath;
  }
}

const getPublicUrl = appPackageJson => envPublicUrl || require(appPackageJson).homepage;

// We use `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable or "homepage" field to infer
// "public path" at which the app is served.
// Webpack needs to know it to put the right <script> hrefs into HTML even in
// single-page apps that may serve index.html for nested URLs like /todos/42.
// We can't use a relative path in HTML because we don't want to load something
// like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
function getServedPath(appPackageJson) {
  const publicUrl = getPublicUrl(appPackageJson);
  const servedUrl = envPublicUrl || (publicUrl ? url.parse(publicUrl).pathname : '/');
  return ensureSlash(servedUrl, true);
}

const moduleFileExtensions = [
  'web.mjs',
  'mjs',
  'web.js',
  'js',
  'web.ts',
  'ts',
  'web.tsx',
  'tsx',
  'json',
  'web.jsx',
  'jsx',
];

// Resolve file paths in the same order as webpack
const resolveModule = (resolveFn, filePath) => {
  const extension = moduleFileExtensions.find(extension =>
    fs.existsSync(resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`)),
  );

  if (extension) {
    return resolveFn(`${filePath}.${extension}`);
  }

  return resolveFn(`${filePath}.js`);
};

// config after eject: we're in ./config/
module.exports = {
  dotenv: resolveApp('.env'),
  appPath: resolveApp('.'),
  appBuild: resolveApp('build'),
  appPublic: resolveApp('public'),
  appHtml: resolveApp('public/index.html'),
  appIndexJs: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/index'),
  appPackageJson: resolveApp('package.json'),
  appSrc: resolveApp('src'),
  appTsConfig: resolveApp('tsconfig.json'),
  appJsConfig: resolveApp('jsconfig.json'),
  yarnLockFile: resolveApp('yarn.lock'),
  testsSetup: resolveModule(resolveApp, 'src/setupTests'),
  proxySetup: resolveApp('src/setupProxy.js'),
  appNodeModules: resolveApp('node_modules'),
  publicUrl: getPublicUrl(resolveApp('package.json')),
  servedPath: getServedPath(resolveApp('package.json')),
};

module.exports.moduleFileExtensions = moduleFileExtensions;

module.exports.lernaRoot = path.resolve(module.exports.appPath, '../../');

module.exports.appLernaModules = [];
module.exports.allLernaModules = fs.readdirSync(path.join(module.exports.lernaRoot, 'packages'));

fs.readdirSync(module.exports.appNodeModules).forEach(folderName => {
  if (folderName === 'react-scripts') {
    return;
  }
  const fullName = path.join(module.exports.appNodeModules, folderName);
  if (fs.lstatSync(fullName).isSymbolicLink()) {
    module.exports.appLernaModules.push(fs.realpathSync(fullName));
  }
});
```

tsconfig:

```
// base in root
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}

//packages/web/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to add my 2 cents, as I was having this problem. I did try initially to compile the shared components folder, but it was awful... It took too long.

Here I am showing you how to do this with `react-scripts` v4 and `TypeScript` **without ejecting** (We will need to use craco, otherwise it's not possible).

Here's the step by step.

1. Point your shared component folder, in this case, `common` to the main .tsx or .ts file.
2. Create a `craco.config.js` file that loads the babel-loader and transpiles it. This file needs to be copied in every individual application that common is trying to be loaded to.

---

1. Pointing your shared component folder.
   Open your `common`'s `package.json` (Not the root!):

[image: Step 1]

Check that you have the name you'd like to import it from (I'm using in the picture an example of my actual application), have the `private` set as `true`, and the `source`, `main`, and `module` entries, have them pointed to your entry file. In my case it was the `index.ts`

```json
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "source": "index.ts",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "module": "./index.ts",
// The common's package.json content
...
}
```

2. In **every other repo** that you'd like to reference your `common` package from, create a `craco.config.js` file, and include the following:

```
const path = require('path');
/**
 * ALlows us to edit create-react-app configuration
 * without ejecting.
 *
 *
 */
const { getLoader, loaderByName } = require('@craco/craco');
// Replace `components` with your folder's structure.
// Again, Here I'm showcasing my current project.
const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../components');
/**
 * This is extremely important if you're using a CI/CD to build and deploy 
 * your code!!! Read!
 * 
 * If you create a package with a namespace, such as name is @schon/components, you need
 * to add what I've commented down below. Otherwise Yarn will fail in CI/CD environments!!
 */
// const schonComponents = path.join(
//   __dirname,
//   './node_modules/@schon/components',
// );

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      // https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-create-react-app-in-a-monorepo-a4e6f25be7aa
      const { isFound, match } = getLoader(
        webpackConfig,
        loaderByName('babel-loader'),
      );
      if (isFound) {
        const include = Array.isArray(match.loader.include)
          ? match.loader.include
          : [match.loader.include];
        // match.loader.include = include.concat(absolutePath, schonComponents);
        match.loader.include = include.concat(absolutePath);
      }
      return {
        ...webpackConfig,
        /**
         * Optionally, other webpack configuration details.
         */
        // optimization: {
        //   splitChunks: {
        //   },
        // },
      };
    },
  },
  
};
```

[image: step 2]

Comment: I've got a similar solution at the moment leveraging `craco`. However my intelisense tries to import from relative path when importing from `common` instead of using the package name. Is that true for you as well?

Comment: As an example:
`import {x} from '../common'` instead of `import {x} from '@scope/common'`. Both of them seem to work fine just intellisense seems to only identify the relative import.

Comment: On a side note, `const absolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '../components');` needs to be modified to the path appropriate for your project. In my case, I had to change `../components` to `../ui`.

Answer (score 3):

Got it working eventually. To get TS to work, you need to explicitly add presets: `['@babel/preset-typescript', { allExtensions: true, isTSX: true }], ['@babel/preset-react'],` to your loader in addition to the linked solution:

```js
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: [paths.appSrc, ...paths.appLernaModules],
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'),
                presets: [// ADD THESE
                  ['@babel/preset-typescript', { allExtensions: true, isTSX: true }],
                  ['@babel/preset-react'],
                ],
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
```

Comment: Does this mean that you ejected, so you’re not really using create react app anymore?
I can’t find any way to access these config files without ejecting.

Comment: could you please share your repo somewhere? I really hope to get it working using cra-override without ejecting

Comment: Yeah this is definitely ejected. If you go the monorepo route you will probably have to eject relatively quickly.

Comment: @BrookJordan you could use craco or similar to override without ejecting https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/tree/master/packages/craco

Answer (score 2):

As @BrandonM mentioned in his answer, modifying the ejected `webpack.config.js` file works.
This is due to Babel not having the necessary information when running in a different directory above the current project root, *because that info is in the `package.json` file*!

Creating a `babel.config.json` and moving the configuration over from `package.json` also solves the problem and is cleaner than modifying the `webpack.config.js`.

That did the trick for me:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

My personal solution for TypeScript + React + Monorepo also includes the `tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin` as mentioned in the blog post from Adrei Picus https://medium.com/@NiGhTTraX/making-typescript-monorepos-play-nice-with-other-tools-a8d197fdc680 , so that I can use my aliases in `tsconfig.json` without having to redefine them:

```
tsconfig.json
/packages
  /A
    /src
    tsconfig.json
  /B
    /src
    tsconfig.json
```

(root) `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@my-app/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

(A and B) `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig",
  "compilerOptions": {
    // your config
    // do not add baseUrl or paths
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the example config of your babel.config.json and .babelrc file in package. I have the same changes and it doesn't seem to be working for me.